# Make a table out of meta box

Tags: functions

I want to display the information for my custom metabox as a table on my posts. First question is, how do I make a table out of the information, and secondly, how do I call the metabox?

Also, can I have the table disappear if nothing is filled in?

```
$prefix = 'anime_';

$anime_box = array(
    'id' => 'anime-meta-box',
    'title' => 'Anime Details',
    'page' => 'post',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'desc' => 'Add the name of the Anime in either English or Japanese(Romanji).',
            'id' => $prefix . 'anime_name',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Genre',
            'desc' => 'Is it a thriller, action/adventure, etc...',
            'id' => $prefix . 'anime_genre',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Directed by',
            'desc' => 'Name of director(s).',
            'id' => $prefix . 'anime_director',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Music by',
            'desc' => 'Name of composer(s)',
            'id' => $prefix . 'anime_music',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Studio',
            'desc' => 'Studio which owns the anime.',
            'id' => $prefix . 'anime_studio',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
         array(
            'name' => 'Licensed by',
            'desc' => 'Name of both American and Japanese license holders.',
            'id' => $prefix . 'anime_license',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Network(s)',
            'desc' => 'Networks which air the show in both Japan and the United States.',
            'id' => $prefix . 'anime_network',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
         array(
            'name' => 'Original run',
            'desc' => 'Date of when the anime first aired and when it stopped.',
            'id' => $prefix . 'anime_run',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Episodes',
            'desc' => 'Number of episodes.',
            'id' => $prefix . 'anime_episodes',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),

    )
);

add_action('admin_menu', 'anime_add_box');

// Add meta box
function anime_add_box() {
    global $anime_box;

    add_meta_box($anime_box['id'], $anime_box['title'], 'anime_show_box', $anime_box['page'], $anime_box['context'], $anime_box['priority']);
}

// Callback function to show fields in meta box
function anime_show_box() {
    global $anime_box, $post;

    // Use nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="anime_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';

    echo '<table class="form-table">';

    foreach ($anime_box['fields'] as $field) {
        // get current post meta data
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

        echo '<tr>',
                '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '"><strong>', $field['name'], ':</strong></label></th>',
                '<td>';
        switch ($field['type']) {
            case 'text':
                echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />',
                    '<br /><small>', $field['desc'],'</small>';
                break;

        }
        echo    '<td>',
            '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'anime_save_data');

// Save data from meta box
function anime_save_data($post_id) {
    global $anime_box;

    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['anime_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    foreach ($anime_box['fields'] as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any progress on this one?

Comment: Yes, the answer below was enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each field in the meta box is being saved as post meta (a.k.a. custom fields). You can display the info per-field with the `get_post_meta` function, i.e.:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'anime_anime_genre', true ); ?>
```

The parameter in the middle (`anime_anime_genre`) is each field ID specified in your code above.  The reason "anime" appears twice is because that's how you've written it: the ID is set to `$prefix . 'anime_genre'`, and your $prefix is set to `anime_`.

To make the data appear below post content, you're going to have to find the appropriate template file in your theme to edit.  Once you do, just make an HTML table...

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Genre</th></tr>
    <tr><td><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'anime_anime_genre', true ); ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

And finally, to "make the table disappear if nothing is filled in", just use if statements:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'anime_anime_genre', true ) ) { ... } ?>
```

Beyond that, I'd recommend looking up some basic PHP tutorials, as well as checking out the WordPress Codex to learn about theme development and see how things like custom fields work.

Comment: `<tr><th>Genre</th></tr>` would lead to a better css

Comment: Nice catch - edited my response.